# ReferenceError: Unknown plugin "transform-runtime" specified in package.json" at 0

Tags: ripple

i'm using RippleAPI and i installed all thr pre-requisites for it. 
1) install Node.js and npm
 node version is 5.6.0
This is beginner guide :
https://ripple.com/build/rippleapi-beginners-guide/

i'm facing that issue while running ripple API

```
 ReferenceError: Unknown plugin "transform-runtime" specified in 
 "DIRECTORY\\ripple\\my_ripple_experiment\\node_modules\\regenerator- 
 transform\\package.json" at 0, attempted to resolve relative to 
 :\\ripple\\my_ripple_experiment\\node_modules\\regenerator-transform" 
 (While processing preset: "E:\\ripple\\my_ripple_experiment
  \\node_modules\\babel-preset-es2015\\lib\\index.js")
 at E:\ripple\my_ripple_experiment\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation
\file\options\option-manager.js:180:17
at Array.map (<anonymous>)
at Function.normalisePlugins (E:\ripple\my_ripple_experiment\node_modules\ba
bel-core\lib\transformation\file\options\option-manager.js:158:20)
at OptionManager.mergeOptions (E:\ripple\my_ripple_experiment\node_modules\b
abel-core\lib\transformation\file\options\option-manager.js:234:36)
at OptionManager.init (E:\ripple\my_ripple_experiment\node_modules\babel-cor
 e\lib\transformation\file\options\option-manager.js:368:12)
at compile (E:\ripple\my_ripple_experiment\node_modules\babel-register\lib\n
 ode.js:103:45)
at loader (E:\ripple\my_ripple_experiment\node_modules\babel-register\lib\no
de.js:144:14)
at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (E:\ripple\my_rip
ple_experiment\node_modules\babel-register\lib\node.js:154:7)
at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
```

Let me know who i can solve this transform-runtime problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try running `npm install babel-plugin-transform-runtime`.

At least, that fixed this for me in a different setup.